# How do i handle imports inside an es module?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, module

I'm working on a system where i can dynamically fetch a component from server and draw it on my page.

I have a small vue test component that looks like this:

```js
<template>
  <div class="wrapper-box">
    <h1>Hello, {{ username }}</h1>
    <button @click="tryRandomize">Randomize name</button>
    <p>This is your new component</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

let username = ref("Jack");

const names = ["Max", "Larry", "Johnny", "Alex"];

const getRandomName = () => {
  return names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
};

const tryRandomize = () => {
  let newName = getRandomName();

  if (newName !== username.value) {
    username.value = newName;
  } else {
    tryRandomize();
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.wrapper-box {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 1rem;
}
</style>
```

I run `vite build` and get this small test module (es format):

```js
(function(){"use strict";try{if(typeof document<"u"){var e=document.createElement("style");e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(".wrapper-box[data-v-39582ec0]{display:grid;place-items:center;border:1px solid lightgrey;width:600px;margin:1rem}")),document.head.appendChild(e)}}catch(t){console.error("vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js",t)}})();
import { ref as r, openBlock as l, createElementBlock as p, createElementVNode as s, toDisplayString as _, unref as m, pushScopeId as i, popScopeId as d } from "vue";
const u = (e, o) => {
  const t = e.__vccOpts || e;
  for (const [c, n] of o)
    t[c] = n;
  return t;
}, h = (e) => (i("data-v-39582ec0"), e = e(), d(), e), f = { class: "wrapper-box" }, v = /* @__PURE__ */ h(() => /* @__PURE__ */ s("p", null, "This is your new component", -1)), y = {
  __name: "SimpleComponent",
  setup(e) {
    let o = r("Jack");
    const t = ["Max", "Larry", "Johnny", "Alex"], c = () => t[Math.floor(Math.random() * t.length)], n = () => {
      let a = c();
      a !== o.value ? o.value = a : n();
    };
    return (a, x) => (l(), p("div", f, [
      s("h1", null, "Hello, " + _(m(o)), 1),
      s("button", { onClick: n }, "Randomize name"),
      v
    ]));
  }
}, g = /* @__PURE__ */ u(y, [["__scopeId", "data-v-39582ec0"]]);
export {
  g as default
};
```

Now, when i load it locally like so:

```js
<template>
  <component :is="comp"></component>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

const comp = ref(null);

import(
  "../../dist/simpleComponent.js"
)
  .then(({ default: mod }) => {
    comp.value = mod;
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.error(`You got an error: ${e}`);
  });
</script>
```

everything works like expected, but when i put the same module on the server and try to import from there:
`import( "https://myServer/simpleComponent.js" )`
i get this:

- `You got an error: TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

Looks like it can't resolve the import but why? Everything works fine locally. What am i doing wrong?